# I want to get rid of Ubuntu and boot my Windows 8 partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, gpt

I've installed Ubuntu many times but since I purchased a new laptop (Lenovo Y580) I wanted to try Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 on it. So, without knowing what was UEFI nor GPT I installed it and everything was fine until I tryed to boot Windows. I did make a partition for Ubuntu without even touching all of the other ones, I can browse them in Ubuntu but I can't boot the important one, only recovery and such but they don't seem to fix it (Automatic Recovery from Windows) so I don't have any image to recover from and I have tryed everything from CMD aswell. I need to boot up that partition in dev/sda5 to make an image backup or something to get it back to default settings since I have all the partitions intact.

gdisk (p command)

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
    Logical sector size: 512 bytes
    Disk identifier (GUID): 05DDAADB-BAED-46DE-94FD-AD3B74A521D9
    Partition table holds up to 128 entries
    First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
    Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
    Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)
    Number Start (sector) End (sector) Size Code Name
    1 2048 2050047 1000.0 MiB 2700 Basic data partition
    2 2050048 2582527 260.0 MiB EF00 EFI system partition
    3 2582528 4630527 1000.0 MiB FFFF Basic data partition
    4 4630528 4892671 128.0 MiB 0C01 Microsoft reserved part
    5 4892672 1859151871 884.2 GiB EF00 Basic data partition
    6 1859151872 1911580671 25.0 GiB 0700 Basic data partition
    7 1911580672 1953523711 20.0 GiB 2700 Basic data partition
```

and boot-repair log http://paste.ubuntu.com/5560680

Comment: Related : http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me I had to insert a windows 7 disc and run the tool to fix the mbr from recovery mode. After I did that I booted into windows and used the disk manager to remove the Ubuntu partition.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) is some instruction on using Bootrec.exe

---

The funny thing is I wasn't able to do this with a Windows 8 disc and I had to use my older Windows 7 disc.. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I've used Bootrec, fixboot, fixmbr on sda5 and rebuild BCD on the UEFI 260mb partition, all "succeded" but they didn't fix it. Is there any way to boot sda5 from a cd or something?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you think you've done up to this point, but I do see one glaring error in the partition table: `/dev/sda5` is marked as an EFI System Partition (ESP), but it uses NTFS and is probably your Windows boot partition. This probably happened because you mistakenly set the "boot flag" on the disk using `parted`, GParted, or some other libparted-based tool. You should ***not*** set this "flag" using libparted-based tools on GPT disks *except* on the ESP! I don't know for a fact that Windows would flake out if you attempted to boot it from such a mis-marked partition, but it probably would. Thus, my recommendation is to use `parted`, GParted, `gdisk`, or some similar tool to fix the problem. First, boot a Linux emergency disc. Then, you can do either of two things (both would be redundant):

- Using `parted`, GParted, or another libparted-based tool, remove the "boot flag" from `/dev/sda5`. For instance, you might type `set 5 boot off` in `parted`.
- Using `gdisk`, type `t` to change the type code, type `5` for the partition number, type `0700` as the type code, and then type `w` back at the prompt to save your changes. You could use `cgdisk` instead, if you prefer.

Either of these actions will fix that glaring problem. I don't guarantee that the computer will then become bootable, but I suspect it will.